# Python/ctypes file handle difference between Mac OS X and Ubuntu

Tags: python, ctypes

I am currently attempting to port some code between my linux machine (Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS) and my new Mac (OS X 10.7.4) and I have come across some confusing behavior when using python's ctypes module to access the C standard library on the Mac.

To illustrate the problem, the following is a minimal example:

```
import ctypes as C
import numpy as np

libc = C.CDLL("/usr/lib/libc.dylib")   #/usr/lib/libc.so.6 on ubuntu

np.arange(10,dtype="ubyte").tofile("test.bin") # create some test data

buffer_array = np.empty(10,dtype="ubyte") # create a reading buffer

buffer_array_c = np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(buffer_array) # get the ctypes version of the buffer 

c_file = libc.fopen("test.bin","r") # open the file through libc   

libc.fread(buffer_array_c, 1, 10, c_file) # read from the file

libc.fclose(c_file)

print "Desired output:"
print np.fromfile("test.bin",dtype="ubyte")
print
print "Actual output:"
print buffer_array
```

On Linux, this works as expected, producing the following:

```
Desired output:
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

Actual output:
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

On the Mac however, I just get `Segmentation fault: 11'.

I have experimented with this a bit, swapping out the fopen call with:

```
py_file = open("test.bin","r")

c_file = C.pythonapi.PyFile_AsFile(C.py_object(py_file))
```

Which also works on Linux but not on Mac.

I think the problem is coming from calling fread using c_file, as if I write a minimal C function to open the file then call fread using the previously allocated buffer, the code performs as expected.

I am not normally a Mac user, so the problem may be obvious, but any help would be very useful.

For reference, I am using:

Python 2.7.3,  Numpy 1.4.0 and Ctypes 1.1.0

### Edit:

To give this some context, I am experimenting with fast methods to read very large binary files (~40-200 GB) into python, piece by piece. As a commenter points out below, there is not really any performance increase to be had from directly accessing the standard library fread and fwrite functions. This is true, but I am confused as to why. If I were to use numpy.fromfile to read a large file in chunks, wouldn't I be creating a new memory allocation with each read?

### Solution:

The problem seems to stem from the 64bit/32bit difference in storage of file handles.
The solution is simply to explicitly set the restype and argtypes of each c function prior to use.

i.e on a 64-bit machine we put this after the C.CDLL call:

```
lib.fopen.restype = C.c_long
lib.fread.argtypes = [C.c_void_p, C.c_size_t, C.c_size_t, C.c_long]
lib.fclose.argtypes = [C.c_long]
```

While on a 32-bit machine:

```
lib.fopen.restype = C.c_int
lib.fread.argtypes = [C.c_void_p, C.c_size_t, C.c_size_t, C.c_int]
lib.fclose.argtypes = [C.c_int]
```

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say 'you're doing it wrong'. It's highly unlikely that you'll see any significant performance improvement in IO writing it by hand unless I'm missing something critically important. Can you give a little more context to your task?

Comment: Did you profile before trying your solution? I doubt that the overhead of the multiple allocation is so big that you must use the libc calls.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Much of the data that is being read/written is in a 1-bit format. So I need to read the data as bytes before unpacking the information (in this case many time series). There is a certain convenience to be had from doing this all inside a single buffer. What I have posted is not a `solution' _per se_, it is more of a ctypes learning experiment.

Comment: You could use `py_file = open("test.bin","rb"); py_file.readinto(buffer_array)`. It returns the number of bytes read into the buffer.

Comment: @eryksun: I like the readinto function, but I am wary of using it due to the doc string reading ``readinto() -> Undocumented.  Don't use this; it may go away.''. I don't know if this is still the case in Python 3, but for now np.fromfile runs at about 90% the speed of readinto.

Comment: `readinto` won't go away in 2.7x, and there will never be a 2.8. It's definitely not going away in the 3.x `io` module, which is backported to 2.7 as a built-in. Try the `BufferedReader` returned by `io.open("test.bin","rb")`. It might perform as well as the original 2.x `file` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you trying on a 32-bit Ubuntu versus a 64-bit OS/X?  I think the issue is that your version of libc.fopen() returns a C "int", which is almost always a 32-bit value --- but the real fopen() returns a pointer.  So on a 64-bit operating system, the c_file that you get is truncated to a 32-bit integer.  On a 32-bit operating system, it works anyway because the 32-bit integer can be passed back to the fread() and fclose(), which will interpret it again as a pointer.  To fix it, you need to declare the restype of libc.fopen().

(I can only recommend [CFFI](http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) as an alternative to ctypes with saner defaults, but of course I'm partial there, being one of the authors :-)

Comment: Why does `ctypes` [cast the result to `c_int`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#l894)(callproc.c, `GetResult`) instead of `c_long`, the type used by a [`PyIntObject`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Include/intobject.h#l21)?

Comment: Who knows?  My best bet is that on Win32 (where ctypes was originally developped) it doesn't matter, and from now on not much thought went into it.

Comment: @ArminRigo: Great answer, solved the problem straight away. Also kudos on CFFI. I've been looking for a package that can let me use distutils to install generic c extensions.